# Why when I broadcast_tx_commit (using abci-cli) the output also have the fee field?

Tags: tendermint

`curl -s 'localhost:46657/broadcast_tx_commit?tx="name=satoshi"'`

result contains the `fee` field: `"fee": {}`

Why return the parameter fee? It is different from the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes docs are a little bit behind the development. I updated the docs https://tendermint.readthedocs.io/projects/tools/en/develop/getting-started.html

Comment: Does the parameter fee has the same mean of the gas in Ethereum?

Comment: @RussellZhang please ignore it for now (it does not work). in the future, it will play the same role as Ethereum's gas. We have not decided on the naming however.